# Selector Elements by AttributeS possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Short small question. Can something like that work and when yes does it also work with IE11? And if there are some mistakes please tell me.

```
$("option[class='sorted'] && !(option[title='"+look+"'])").remove;
```

Comment: I suggest reading the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) rather than guessing.

Comment: there was nothing like multiple inputs so i asked.

Comment: [Really? **nothing** like it](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)? Seems to me you didn't read it carefully enough.

Comment: I just found the English one. My native language is German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
$("option.sorted").not("[title='"+look+"']").remove();
```

Doing it this way lets you leverage the performance of the browser's query selector.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use attribute selector in conjuction with `:not()` for negation operation

```
 $("option.sorted:not([title='"+look+"'])").remove();
```